Uncaught TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface URLSearchParams
I am trying to make a php page with pagination function by first submitting a form and then updating the area with a page click function. The Form that will be submitted is like this:
<form class="row g-3" name="search" id="search" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="departmentSer" class="col-form-label">Select Department:</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-select" name="departmentSer" id="departmentSer" aria-label="Default select example">
          <option>Choose1</option>
          <option>Choose2</option>
          <option>Choose3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="lddeptSecSub" name="lddeptSecSub" value="lddeptSearch" onclick="submitFormSea(this.value, 'departmentSer')">Get List</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>

And Following is the HTML area where the result from the ajax query will be updated:
<div class="align-items-center mt-4" id="formShowData" name="formShowData"> </div>
    </div>

The Pagination links are generated like this:
<a class="page-link" href="?areac=lddeptSearch&amp;place=Choose...&amp;dsource=listData&amp;page=1" onclick="submitClick(this)">1</a>
This area is first updated with with a form submit. And then replaced when the pages are clicked. The following jQuery is doing the function:
function jajax_qview(datas, field) {
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax_areac.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datas,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
  });

  request.done(function( msg ) {
      $('#'+field).html(msg);
  });
 
  request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    console.log(datas);
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
  
  request.always(function() {
    datas = undefined;
  });
}

function submitForm(formNameS, elemIdVal) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var datas = {areac:formNameS, place : $('#'+elemIdVal).val()};

  jajax_qview(datas, 'formS');
}

function submitClick(submitLinkVars) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(submitLinkVars.search);
  var datas = searchParams;
  jajax_qview(datas, 'formS');
}

Now the problem is that the function "submitForm" is working perfectly fine, when submitting is generation the required data without any error. But when the page number are clicked, the function submitClick is submitted but I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface URLSearchParams."
And the variable datas that is generated by the function is "submitClick" is URLSearchParams(4) { areac → "lddeptSearch", place → "7", dsource → "listData", page → "2" }
I have tried with ajax parameters processData: false,contentType: false,. When trying with this option, no data is submitted by the ajax method to the php file. And when trying with dataType: "json" I am getting error Request failed: parsererror.
So, how to solve the problem and submit the data when clicking on the page links.

Not sure where append would eventually get called here, that's nowhere in your code. But if passing an actual URLSearchParams instance to jajax_qview in your submitClick function works - then I'd suggest you simply do the same in your submitForm function then - create a URLSearchParams object, and pass that.

I am getting the error...from where? Please provide the stack trace. As above, there is no call to an append function anywhere in the code you've provided.

append is called in jquery-3.7.1.min.js. And the error is because I am calling the ajax function from jquery. So, append is not called in my function, rather then by jquery.

@C3roe I read it saying that using the URLSearchParams was not working, but that passing a regular object (as done in the "submitForm" funtion) was fine. So I think it's the opposite - the OP should not use URLSearchParams. Given it gets passed to $.ajax in the end, I'd suspect jQuery doesn't like receiving one of those as a data object

I am getting the error in the console of the browser.

I am getting the error in the console...yes, we know that...that wasn't my point. By "where" I mean, which line of code and which JS file? And you've told us that it comes from jQuery - thankyou.

I am using the URLSearchParams function to get the parameters from the url for resubmitting to the ajax function.

As per https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, the data option can be a plain object, a string or an array. That suggests it doesn't accept URLSearchParams objects - and the error you're getting seems to back that up. So you need to transform that data before you can pass it to $.ajax

Additionally, but not related: The calls to event.preventDefault() will 100% error out (except if you have a event var-/let-/const-binding somewhere else in your code that you haven't shown).

Click on a a tag is an event, which is prevented here. So, is there any other way to get parameters from URL to be passed to the ajax function

Just convert the params back into a regular querystring, $.ajax will happily accept that (as per its documentation). ToString() on the URLSearchParams object should do the job. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString

@Nilesh: What data are you trying to send to the server in submitClick?  Why can't you just create a plain object with that data exactly as you do in submitForm?  If you've already discovered that one works and the other doesn't, and you can see that the difference between them is the object being passed to it, then what happens when you attempt to modify the failing one to use a plain object like the working one?

@ADyson I don't want toString() function rather I want something like tojason function.
@David As from the submitForm function I am getting a URL with variable, I have to take them and build an array or jason in javascript to be submitted again via sunbitClick function. And so I am using URLSearchParams function to get the variable from URL and submit it back

@Nilesh why would you want to convert it to JSON?? Your $.ajax request is not sending the data in JSON format right now. So it would be incompatible, and also probably your PHP code would have to be changed, in order to read JSON input. There doesn't seem to be any reason to make all that effort, when a simpler solution exists. The data is not sufficiently complex that JSON would be beneficial over a regular querystring, either.

Okay, other way around then. How to convert URL parameters to a JavaScript object?

Clicks  make the browser generate an event object and pass it to the event handler as an argument. This means the handler is required to take the argument, not to reference a "magically" available event binding that nowhere exists. Have a look at MDN

jQuery's $.ajax function does not accept URLSearchParams objects as input to the data option, and that is the source of the error. As per the $.ajax documentation, data can be a plain object, string or array.
The $.ajax documentation states it will accept a URL-like querystring as input (as per the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type):

When data is passed as a string it should already be encoded using the correct encoding for contentType, which by default is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

For your case the simplest thing is probably to use the toString() function of your URLSearchParams object to output the parameters in that format.
The URLSearchParams toString documentation states:

The toString() method of the URLSearchParams interface returns a query
string suitable for use in a URL.

So please try this:
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(submitLinkVars.search);
var datas = searchParams.toString();
jajax_qview(datas, 'formS');


Yes, Thanks. That worked just fine.

@Nilesh If the answer solved your problem "just fine", how about accepting it?

@Davi Thanks, I am almost new here in terms of asking questions. So thanks for the advice, and yes I have accepted the answer.

Apart from passing an unsupported object to AJAX, you need to not use inline click if you want to stop the click.
I suggest Delegation. Change my ID paginationContainer to YOUR closest static container that holds the pagination links or use document if you do not have such a container - note in my example I have two wrappers so I delegate from document:


const jajax_qview = (datas, what) => console.log(what,':',datas); // debug

//document.getElementById('paginationContainer').addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('.page-link');
  if (!tgt) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(tgt.search);
  let datas = searchParams.toString();
  jajax_qview(datas, 'formS');
})
<nav id="topnav">
  <a class="page-link" href="?areac=lddeptSearch&amp;place=Choose...&amp;dsource=listData&amp;page=1">1</a>
  <a class="page-link" href="?areac=lddeptSearch&amp;place=Choose...&amp;dsource=listData&amp;page=2">2</a>
  <a class="page-link" href="?areac=lddeptSearch&amp;place=Choose...&amp;dsource=listData&amp;page=3">3</a>
</nav>

<div id="content">
  <h3>Content</h3>
</div>
<nav id="bottomnav">
  <a class="page-link" href="?areac=lddeptSearch&amp;place=Choose...&amp;dsource=listData&amp;page=1">1</a>
  <a class="page-link" href="?areac=lddeptSearch&amp;place=Choose...&amp;dsource=listData&amp;page=2">2</a>
  <a class="page-link" href="?areac=lddeptSearch&amp;place=Choose...&amp;dsource=listData&amp;page=3">3</a>
</nav>




This sounds alien to me. I mean I don't get this. I have no element with id="paginationContainer"

@Nilesh I'd guess that mplungjan meant the container that wraps your <a class="page-link" ...> elements...

@Davi @mplungjan the problem with wrapping .page-link within another #paginationContainer is that, I have more than one .page-link in the page. All the page numbers I show in the page are of class="page-link", And when we do const tgt = e.target.closest('.page-link');  it will onle select the first .page-link link. The only work around to this, what I see is wrapping every .page-link within a container and having click function for all of them. And above all, I am not getting any error on click event with my element, not even any warning.

YOUR closest static container can be document! document..addEventListener('click', (e) => {    const tgt = e.target.closest('.page-link'); I am DELEGATING to the nearest static container of all the page-links. I would never separately wrap and loop over all things we want to monitor if you can do it with delegation. My code handles ALL the page-links - see update for a runnable example
